# Executing Java code at runtime in Android Application

Tags: android, java

I need a tool to inject a string of code in my already existing code at runtime.
This string is obtained by a http request during the execution and uses some variables that are statically declared in the code (before the compilation).
I have tried to use beanshell but it has a lot of syntax parsing problems.
I would like to use something more advanced, which supports for example lambda functions and the diamond operator (<>). I don't know if it exists.
Thanks to everybody in advance.

Comment: As you mention Beanshell you are looking for a Java library, not a stand-alone tool like Frida. One way would be Groovy Scripting, but I don't know if this is still possible on recent Android versions because of the W^X (write xor execute)  security restriction.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! @Robert